# Form from Model with File Upload

Tags: python, django, forms, webforms, django-forms

I'm trying to mimic the admin interface for the Photologue app on the front end. To achieve this, I have thus far created a bit of code in the view:

```
def galleryuploader(request):
    GalleryFormSet = modelformset_factory(GalleryUpload)    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = GalleryFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            # do something. ... do what?
    else:
        formset = GalleryFormSet()
    return render_to_response("cms_helper/gallery_upload.html", {
        "formset": formset,
    })
```

and a template:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ formset }} 
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I'm using django's "[form from models](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)" method for generating this front-end form.

The problem: when I try to upload a file (because I am uploading photos to a photo gallery), and hit submit, it returns with a form error telling me that a required field was missing (the file).

I think I am not checking the request for any files, but even if I were to, I'm not quite sure how to. Here's some documentation about [file uploads](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/), but I haven't been able to decipher it yet.

If you have any suggestions about how to make this upload form work, I'd be veryyy happy to hear them. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to your form tag.  Also you'll need to actually do something with the uploaded files.  Here's the example from the [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

# Imaginary function to handle an uploaded file.
from somewhere import handle_uploaded_file

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # you'll need to loop through the uploaded files here.
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    destination = open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

(See the comment about halfway through)

Comment: Looking at the Photologue model, I see function called "process_zipfile" as well as "save" within the "GalleryUpload" class. I'm going to take a guess and say that I should be calling these from within my view (as your sample code shows)?

Comment: Bueno. Thanks for the help.. I could have read that myself but it always helps to have it highlighted :P

Comment: @Brian D: Sorry I didn't see your earlier comment.  Second pair of eyes always helps :)  Glad you got it figured out.